# Dynamic dice sum - modulo

Tags: c++

You have d dice, and each die has f faces numbered 1, 2, ..., f.

Return the number of possible ways (out of fd total ways) modulo 10^9 + 7 to roll the dice so the sum of the face up numbers equals target.

My code works well for small values of f,d and target. It gives 0 as answer for big values say 30, 30, 500.

I am getting a lot of difficulty solving where modulo occurs. 
What is wrong with my solution ?

```
int numRollsToTarget(int d, int f, int target)
{
    long long int dp[d][target];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < target; j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < f && i < target; i++)
    {
        dp[0][i] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < target; j++)
        {
            if (j >= i)
                for (int k = max(0, j - f); k < min(j, f); k++)
                    dp[i][j] = (dp[i - 1][j - k - 1] % 1000000007 + 
                               dp[i][j] % 1000000007) % 1000000007;
        }
    }

    return dp[d - 1][target - 1];
}
```

Comment: `long long int dp[d][target];` is not standard C++, it use VLA extension. You might use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j<target; j++)
            {
                if(j>=i) {/*..*/}}` can be simplified to `for(int j = i; j<target; j++)
            {/*...*/}`

Comment: @Jarod42 corrected both mistakes, still giving the same output ie. 0 for big numbers.

Comment: Depending on d and target, that could been a LOT of RAM.  Please confirm you are compiling for a 64-bit target?  Otherwise you may be overflowing your math as well.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It was on LeetCode. I don't know how they provide the test cases. I am not able to get if there is any error in the code that is causing overflow or any other problem.

Comment: How did you correct your mistake for the VLA?  I would suspect `std::vector<std::vector<long long>> dp(d, std::vector<long long>(target));`?  And if so, did you use `at()` instead of `[ ]` to check if you're going out-of-bounds of the vector in your calculations?  Also, websites such as LeetCode do **not** teach how to write **and** diagnose C++ programs properly.  Things like using `vector` and `at()` are two common ways to flush out any bugs concerning data size and data access issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is the logic of my code correct ?

Comment: BTW, if you store value in array with modulo, you don't need to read it with modulo again: `dp[i][j] = (dp[i - 1][j - k - 1] % 1000000007 + 
                               dp[i][j] % 1000000007) % 1000000007` -> `dp[i][j] = (dp[i - 1][j - k - 1] + 
                               dp[i][j]) % 1000000007`. But as my previous remarks, that wouldn't solve your issue.